# How to show files that will be updated from repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using a subversion repository, and TortoiseSVN on the client and want to know if it is possible, (and if Yes .. how) to show files that will be changed or merged with an Update command, without actually executing the Update command?

Like the "Check for Modifications" shows the modifications on the client side, we are looking for something to show the modifications on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`svn status -u`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) from the command line will do that or you can use the more TortoiseSVN styled `tortoiseproc /command:repostatus /path:{your/path/goes/here} /remote`.

However, these are both run from the command line (you can change the path for anything though, including `.` as current directory) so you probably want to add some more work to it such as creating a shortcut somewhere or adding the command to a context menu.